# Search files in folder using part of the name and save/copy to different folder using Python

Tags: python, copy

I have 700 files in a single folder.  I need to find files that have "h10v03" as part of the name and copy them to a different folder using python.

Heres an example of one of the files: MOD10A1.A2000121.h10v03.005.2007172062725.hdf

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it need to be python?
A unix shell does that for you quite fine:

```
cp ./*h10v03* /other/directory/
```

In python I would suggest you take a look at os.listdir() and shutil.copy()

**EDIT:**
some untested code:

```
import os
import shutil

src_dir = "/some/path/"
target_dir = "/some/other/path/"
searchstring = "h10v03"

for f in os.listdir(src_dir):
   if searchstring in f and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(src_dir, f)):
      shutil.copy2(os.path.join(src_dir, f), target_dir)
      print "COPY", f
```

with the glob module (untested):

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

for f in glob.glob("/some/path/*2000*h10v03*"):
   print f
   shutil.copy2(f, os.path.join("/some/target/dir/", os.path.basename(f)))
```

Comment: Yes, it needs to be in Python as this is just a small section of a larger script.  Some example code would be awesome if you have the time to post up.  I should mention that i'm fairly new to python.

Comment: here you go :) - the searchstring in f is case-sensitive, if you need more complex matching you could use regular expressions or the globbing module.

Comment: Yes! thanks for the help.  Also, thanks to everyone who chimed in.  Happy Friday.

Comment: Would the globbing module search for two different parts of a file name.  Using the example file name from the first post, would it be possible to search files that have the combination of "2000" and "h10v03".  This would actually help me further filter my search.

Comment: yes it would :) see http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html Ill edit in an example, because I'm feeling particularly well today :)

Comment: That's the ticket!  Thanks once again.  Also appreciate the reference.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do the trick.

```
import os
import shutil

source_dir = "/some/directory/path"
target_dir = "/some/other/directory/path"

part = "h10v03"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(source_dir)
            if os.path.isfile(file) and part in file]
for file in files:
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(source_dir, file), target_dir)
```

Comment: Didn't work.  The only think I altered was source_dir and tartget_dir.  Something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, find all the items in that folder with [os.listdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir). Then you can use the `count()` method of string to determine if it has your string. Then you can use [shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) to copy the file.